# How to convert S3Object to File and return the File Object in Java using try with resources?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3, inputstream

I have a `service` method which returns a `File Object` from **AWS S3** bucket given a `fileName`.
I would like to convert the S3Object to a File object and return the same.

I do not want to use any **temp** location to download the file, just want to convert the `S3Object` to `File` Object and return it.

I would also like to use `try` *with resources* and `IOUtils` for the same.

My question is what is the right way to perform `com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out)` method to get the **File** Object. 
This File object will be used by the calling method for further processing hence I do not want to save it locally. 
I tried something like this but it throws FileNotFoundException.

I am sure I am missing something in this, may be **IOUtils.copy** has to be used differently. or I am not using try with resources correctly.

```
    public File getFileFromBucket(String fileName) {
        GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(aWSBucketName, fileName);
        S3Object s3Object = aWSS3client.getObject(getObjectRequest);
        File s3File = new File(fileName);
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(s3File)) { //throws Exception
            IOUtils.copy(s3Object.getObjectContent(), fos); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.debug("IOException Occurred while fetching file {}", fileName);
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
        return s3File;
    }
```

What is the right way to return the File? 
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

**Edit**

If I do not want to save a File Object locally, is it advisable to return the **InputStream** to the calling method?

As mentioned, the calling method uses `apache poi` library to parse the excel file.

`org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.XSSFWorkbook(InputStream is)` 
this method anyway takes `InputStream` as a param.

I do not know why I wanted to convert it to a **File** to begin with.

**Question:**

Is it advisable to send the `S3Object.getObjectContent()` as an `InputStream` to the calling method or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: A `File` object describes an entry on a **local filesystem**. By definition, an S3 object is *not* on a local filesystem, so it cannot be represented by a `File` any more than a resource inside a jar can. So what you are asking for is impossible. However, it seems that your program merely copies from S3 to a local file. So not sure why you are saying you do not want to save it locally. That's what you are doing. What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: I did not know that `File` object is used to save objects locally. I considered File as something similar to a POJO which can be used to save some information, and then use getters to get that information.
For example- I will send back the File to calling method, this is an excel file which will be used to save user info, the calling method will parse the excel file, using apache poi and then extract information from it and save it to DB.
If what I am asking is wrong, could you please suggest what is the best way to send back this S3 object which can be parsed by calling method?

Comment: No, read the [JavaDoc for `File`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html). It's just a representation of a path in the local filesystem. It doesn't actually contain anything and the path doesn't even have to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting my seniors I found that it is fine to send the `InputStream` to the calling method.

If the `InputStream` needs to be save to a local system, then `IOUtils.copy` can be used whenever necessary.

Conversion of `InputStream` to `File` and then back to `InputStream` is a waste of computation.

Hence my method is simply returning the `ObjectContent` like this:

```
public InputStream getFileInputStreamFromBucket(String fileName) {
        GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(aWSBucketName, fileName);
        S3Object s3Object = aWSS3client.getObject(getObjectRequest);
        InputStream fileInputStream = s3Object.getObjectContent();
        log.debug("File Input Stream fetched from s3 bucket for File {} ", fileName);
        return fileInputStream;
    }
```

This seems to be the right choice.

If anyone has a better way to send back the `InputStream` please feel free to Post an answer.